Applying Span Classes to Style Specific Words Without Styling Attached Punctuation
I'm trying to wrap specific words ("Ethan", "passionate", "UX/UI", and "Designer") in a span class in a paragraph for individual styling. However, since "Ethan" is followed directly by a comma in the HTML, the JavaScript only selects it if I include the comma ("Ethan,")—resulting in the comma being styled as well, which I don't want. How can I apply the style only to "Ethan" without affecting the comma?
Here's my current JS:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const herotext = document.getElementById('herotext');
  const words = herotext.innerText.split(' ');
    
  herotext.innerHTML = words.map(word => {
    if (['Ethan', 'passionate', 'UX/UI', 'Designer'].includes(word))
    {
      return `<span style="color: #F33;">${word}</span>`;
    } else {
      return `<span>${word}</span>`;
    }
  });
});        

And the HTML:
<h1 id="herotext">Hi, I&#8217;m Ethan, a passionate UX/UI Designer from the scenic landscapes of Northern Ireland.</h1>

Thanks!
I’ve already tried wrapping the word "Ethan" in a <span> element and applying a specific CSS style to it, but this didn’t work. The issue is that in the HTML, "Ethan," appears as a single entity (with the comma directly after the name), preventing the span from targeting just "Ethan."
Here's the HTML I used:
<h1 id="herotext">Hi, I’m <span class="highlight">Ethan</span>, a passionate UX/UI Designer from the scenic landscapes of Northern Ireland.</h1>

And the CSS:
.highlight {
    color: #333;
}

I know this is a very specific use case, but this is the only sentence I want to apply this algorithm to. Setting some rules around excluding commas from the styling seems like it would resolve the issue, I'm just not sure how to do this as I'm not a developer and have very very basic development knowledge - some help/a solution would be massively appreciated!

FYI, words.map() produces an array, which you then cram into innerHTML, which expects a string value. This causes extra commas to be inserted because JS will apply join() to create a string from the array.

you can apply the span styling to the specific words without affecting punctuation like THIS


const wordsToHighlight = ["Ethan", "passionate", "UX/UI", "Designer"];
        const heading = document.getElementById("herotext");
        
        function highlightWords(element, words) {
            let html = element.innerHTML;
        
            words.forEach(word => {
                
                const regex = new RegExp(`\\b(${word})\\b`, 'g');
                html = html.replace(regex, `<span class="highlight">$1</span>`);
            });
        
            element.innerHTML = html;
        }
        
        
        highlightWords(heading, wordsToHighlight);
.highlight{
color:blue;
}
 <h1 id="herotext">Hi, I&#8217;m Ethan, a passionate UX/UI Designer from the scenic landscapes of Northern Ireland.</h1>




Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

You can split by the keywords, followed by space or comma (look-ahead regex of (?=[, ]), the regex being new RegExp(word + "(?=[, ])", 'g')) and join back by word being inserted into the template of your preference, looping the keyword array in the process.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const herotext = document.getElementById('herotext');
  const keywords = ['Ethan', 'passionate', 'UX/UI', 'Designer'];
  let temp = herotext.innerText;
  for (let word of keywords) {
      temp = temp.split(new RegExp(word + "(?=[, ])", 'g')).join(`<span style="color: #F33;">${word}</span>`)
  }
  herotext.innerHTML = temp;
  
    
});
.highlight {
    color: #333;
}
<h1 id="herotext">Hi, I&#8217;m Ethan, a passionate UX/UI Designer from the scenic landscapes of Northern Ireland.</h1>




Thanks a lot! I appreciate the solution :)

@Ethan happy to help!

In your map, you can use replace() to clean up the words, as follows.
And if you want to have space between your words, instead of commas, you can use .join(' ') on the array


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const herotext = document.getElementById('herotext');
  const words = herotext.innerText.split(' ');
    
  herotext.innerHTML = words.map(word => {
    const clean_word = word.replace(",","")
    if (['Ethan', 'passionate', 'UX/UI', 'Designer'].includes(clean_word))
    {
      return `<span style="color: #F33;">${clean_word}</span>,`;
    } else {
      return `<span>${word}</span>`;
    }
  });
});
.highlight {
    color: #333;
}
<h1 id="herotext">Hi, I’m <span class="highlight">Ethan</span>, a passionate UX/UI Designer from the scenic landscapes of Northern Ireland.</h1>




I don't think all those commas are meant to be there.... seems to me those should be spaces.

I don't think so either, but it's the code provided by OP. And I told them how to get rid of them using .join() if they aren't meant to be there

You've inserted lots of commas...

I didn't insert anything, I used the code OP provided and modified it only to give an answer to the original question. If OP doesn't like commas, they can ask/search how to  join (wink wink) an array into a string with spaces rather than commas

@JulienRipet the commas were not there in the original input. Therefore the code you have written damages the input text. It's not about liking or disliking commas, but about not damaging the input. There was no comma between "the" and "scenic" in the original, so there should be no comma between the two in your code either.

@LajosArpad have you tried to run the code OP gave? I assure you it inserts comma, whether that's "damage" or intended is not for me to judge

Well, if you turned back the commas to spaces, as I also think you should, you'll notice that the comma after "Nathan" has disappeared. In other words: You join solution doesn't quite work.

@JulienRipet the reason as of why the question was asked was that the code the asker has written was not working as expected. Since he/she wants to highlight keywords and did not mention that spaces need to be replaced with comma and it is quite obviously not his/her goal, presuming that his/her code is correct in making the text humanly unreadable whereas he/she wanted to make it more readable by highlighting words, which can only serve the purpose of making it more readable, I'm pretty sure the commas are unwanted.

@KIKOSoftware True, I inserted clean_word instead of word. I'll fix that, thanks

@LajosArpad And that's why I added And if you want to have space between your words, instead of commas, you can use .join(' ') on the array, because I suspected it, but I can't speak for them, can I? (Btw, you can use them instead of he/she everywhere)

@JulienRipet sure. This is the specific reason I did not down-vote your answer. But it would be a better answer than it is if you would invert it, that is, make it work intuitively and leave a note what needs to be done if commas are preferred. In my view that would largely improve upon your answer.
